# If $L_1 \leq_m L_2$, and $L_2$ is decidable, is $L_1$ then decidable?

Tags: formal-languages, reductions, decidability

There is a lemma in our textbook that asks us to prove the following:

If $L_1 \leq_m L_2$, and $L_2$ is decidable, then $L_1$ is decidable

I tried proving this by saying that if $L_1 \leq_m L_2$, there is a function $f$ such that $f(L_1) \subseteq L_2$. But I know for a fact that a subset of a decidable language is not always decidable (e.g. $\Sigma^*$ and $A_{TM}$). But then I'm definitely stuck since I don't see any other way to prove this.

Comment: Use the fact that, by definition of  $L_1 \le_m L_2$, there is a computable function $f$ such that $x \in L_1 \iff f(x) \in L_2$  and the fact that $L_2$ is decidable.

Comment: Yeah, $f(x)$ would then be decidable, so if $f(x) \in L_2$, then $x \in L_1$, meaning we can decide for any $x$ if $x \in L_1$, so $L_1$ is decidable. Would this be a correct reasoning?

Comment: This is exactly what you need.